# Detect BACKGROUND mode when APP receive external notification in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is my first question after using the knowledge here for more than 1 year.

This is my problem. I'm developing an APP which allow you to record your location in order to save routes. The main goal of the APP is learn to do not touch your phone when you are driving after start a new route. I can detect when the user sleep the phone and when they unlock the phone and return to the APP except in a specific scenario. Let me explain my self with the following steps:

1. The user open the APP.
2. The user start to record a new route
3. The user sleep the phone
4. Then a external notification arrives (like a Viber or Whatsapp message).
5. The user unlock the phone and then iOS switch to the APP which received the notification <--- for a weird reason I'm unable to detect this switch. I don't need to application name or what the user do after this, I only need to know if my APP goes to background mode.

¿Any answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this call in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I guess this method don't work in the above scenario. It only works when the APP are on focus... ¿it's possible to block the "sleep" mode in the device like when you are watching a video?

Comment: What about `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`?  edit:  I guess that gets called when the lock screen.

Comment: Isn't the app in the background mode the whole time?

Comment: Yeah, just checked it.  You get the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` when they lock the screen.  Then if they jump out to another app off of a lock screen notification, you never enter the foreground, so your app just continues to run in background mode.  Why do you need to know that this specific action has happened if you are still just in background mode?

Comment: Actually this is the focus of the APP. People need to learn to do not touch the device when they are driving. ¿It's possible to lock the "spleep" mode in the device? Like when you are watching a video... in this way I can show a alert to the user to don't sleep the device.

Comment: So you want the app to lock the screen on and not allow sleep mode?  And send an alert to not touch the device?  Either way, if a notification comes in, they are going to be able to navigate away.  You can disable "autosleep" with this: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];` but you can't keep them from locking the screen manually.

Comment: Well, if the user manually lock the screen it's good for me because they don't touch the phone after they start to record a route. Thanks!